# How to fix the error 'The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context'?

Tags: c#

Can someone teach me how to resolve this issue? Its a Windows Console Application.

[image]

I have already implemented and put `using System.Web;` but there is still the error regarding `HttpContext` not existing in the current context.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a web site, but a console application. You can't use `HttpContext` in a console application. It doesn't make sense since it is specific to ASP.NET web sites.

Comment: It seems you have to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` instead.

Comment: yes Sir Patrick. I'm using console only because im trying to get the encrypt string of des key only.

Answer (score 4):

For your purpose use any of the below options:

1. `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode()` method in `System.Web` namespace.

   You can refer the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2
2. `WebUtility.UrlDecode()` method in `System.Net` namespace.

   You can refer the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netframework-4.7.2

Your code using HttpContext is suitable to be used in a Web Application Project.

Thanks @dlatikay, @soulflyman for more insight and helping the community.

Comment: Or use HttpUtility.UrlDecode() for better code portability (.net core, xamarin,...) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode

Comment: note that `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode` is nothing else that a `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode`, but in earlier framework versions it is not static, so you'd need an instance, and the documentation says "To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the [WebUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netframework-4.7.2) class".